# Remove read more

Tags: posts, php, read-more

I'm using 3.5.1 and WP UI plugin. When i create a post, add automatically Read More button. 
Like this:

```
<p class="wpui-readmore"><a title="Read more from NEWS" href="http://mysite.com/my-text/" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all">Read More...</a></p>
```

But i cannot use Read More options anyway on my site.

Whats best way remove this option?

Comment: I guess you think that we know that plugin, right? And the same about your theme, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your theme is using the_excerpt() instead of the_content() when displaying the post. If you want to display the full post you'll need to edit your index.php file to use the_content() instead.